# FFmpeg & iPhone: don't display audio language button

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, metadata, ios, mp4

I'm creating an MP4 file with [FFmpeg 1.1.1](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#release_1.1), using [`life`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#life) and [`aevalsrc`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aevalsrc) to generate some test video and audio:

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i life -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -frames:v 750 life.mp4`

If I play it on an iPhone running iOS 4.1, an audio language button appears (indicated by the yellow arrow) which is not normally displayed when other MP4 files are played:

[image: iPhone video screen]

Tapping this button brings up an audio language screen, with "Undetermined" being the only option:

[image: iPhone video screen, audio language option]

Using FFprobe to show the stream info, I can see a `"language": "und"` metadata tag in the video and audio streams:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams life.mp4

{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_type": "video",
            ...
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            ...
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "SoundHandler"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I also have an old MP4 file containing the `"language": "und"` metadata tag which does *not* cause the audio language button to appear on the iPhone. So the presence of this tag is not the cause of the button appearing.

I've been trying to figure out what causes the audio language button to be displayed for some MP4 files but not others.

Here's the FFprobe output for these two MP4 files, and the diff of them:

- [Button not displayed](http://pastebin.com/br005WJA)
- [Button is displayed](http://pastebin.com/C6gRqdMB)
- [diff](http://pastebin.com/f1b2qvpu)

Could the difference in the `compatible_brands` value be the cause? It's `"mp41"` when the button isn't displayed, and `"isomiso2avc1mp41"` when the button is displayed.

Here's the [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) output for these two MP4 files, and the diff of them:

- [Button not displayed](http://pastebin.com/JqBaFjpH)
- [Button is displayed](http://pastebin.com/fi2GNSWd)
- [diff](http://pastebin.com/42nW4beu)

So my question is: how can I get FFmpeg to generate an MP4 file which does not cause the audio language button to appear on the iPhone? Maybe a metadata tag needs to be added or removed using the [`-metadata`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) option?

Many thanks in advance for your help!